# Swift 3 triggering segue causes crash

Tags: segue

Hi am trying to perform a segue by entering a specific word in a textfield.
So far my noob skills brought me to this. 
I don't get an error, the simulator just crashes.

Any hints?

import UIKit

class CodewordVC: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var passWordInput: UITextField!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

passWordInput.delegate = self
    }

```
@IBAction func LosButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //passwords
     let realPassword1 = "rudi"

    if passWordInput.text == realPassword1 {
 self .performSegue(withIdentifier: "rudi", sender: self)
}

func dismissButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work!
Can't really explain, but that would be the answer:

```
import UIKit

class CodewordVC: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var passWordInput: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    let realPassword1 = "rudi"

    @IBAction func LosButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        passWordInput.delegate = self
        //passwords

        if self.passWordInput.text == realPassword1 {

            DispatchQueue.main.async(){

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "rudi", sender: self)

            }
        }
    }

    func dismissButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```